# Why does Spring Boot not load my translations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My system locale is set to german and I set the default locale of the JVM that runs my Spring Boot app to english before I create the Spring context, so that users will get english messages by default:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

I configured the `MessageSource` basename in the application.properties file: `spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages`

The `i18n` folder contains two files (`messages.properties` and `messages_de.properties`).

When I make a request to the server, my browser sends this header:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=0F053562F8BE45E24489097E5B7A1F0C
Host:localhost:8080
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
```

and gets the following header back:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language:de-DE
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 06 Oct 2015 07:50:59 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

But the messages on the website are still in english. Obviously Spring resolved the correct locale based on the request header. So why does it not load the messages from the german file?

**Update**

I did a quick test in a `CommandLineRunner`:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Override
public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
    System.out.println("*                                                                              *");
    System.out.format("* Englisch: %-13s                                                      *\n",
            messageSource.getMessage("views.menu.settings", args, Locale.US));
    System.out.format("* Deutsch : %-13s                                                      *\n",
            messageSource.getMessage("views.menu.settings", args, Locale.GERMANY));
    System.out.format("* China   : %-13s                                                      *\n",
            messageSource.getMessage("views.menu.settings", args, Locale.CHINA));
    System.out.println("*                                                                              *");
    System.out.println("********************************************************************************");
}
```

The expected output is

```
********************************************************************************
*                                                                              *
* Englisch: Settings                                                           *
* Deutsch : Einstellungen                                                      *
* China   : Settings                                                           *
*                                                                              *
********************************************************************************
```

but instead I got

```
********************************************************************************
*                                                                              *
* Englisch: Settings                                                           *
* Deutsch : Settings                                                           *
* China   : Settings                                                           *
*                                                                              *
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: this is so strange, i have the exact same configuration and on my side works as expected... You can try following: 
`@Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;
@RequestMapping(value = "/messages", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getMessages() {
        return Arrays.asList(messageSource.getMessage("your prop name",null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
    }`

and execute curl :
`curl -i -H "Accept-Language:de-DE"  -X GET http://localhost:8080/messages` and see the result

Comment: have you tried to use full locale ( de-DE ) in file name?

Comment: Yes, but it has no effect.

Comment: are you sure about the content in your messages_*.properties files? Looks like they have same content?

Comment: I am. I did a `mvn clean install` and now it's working like expected. I don't know why this happened, because I'm pretty sure that I cleaned the project before, too.

Comment: cool. I saw that your code was ok.